# restrict notification for flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want restrict all types of notifications (WhatsApp, Instagram, Facebook, etc.)when specific page in flutter app is opened. how can I achieve it ? is there any package available ?

Its like a game mode when the app is opened user will not get disturbed by any other app notification

Answer (score 2):

You can use this package
[Flutter Dnd](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dnd)

and when that page is opened, activate dnd
and when that page is collapsed turn it back to previous state (Store the previous state before setting a new state).
You can get current state using `getCurrentInterruptionFilter` function.

But as of now it only supports Android.